# Extracting By Mask list of raster files using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I'm trying to mask a group of raster files and save the new rasters in a different folder using the same name of the original files.

It doesn't sound as a difficult task, but I'm having trouble saving-naming each masked raster inside the "for" loop. Here is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = "C:/rasters/threshold"
mask = "C:/GIS/mesoamerica.tif"

rasterlist = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Raster")
    for i in rasterlist:
        outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(i, mask)
        outExtractByMask.save("C:/SIG/MelasCA_30runs_avg/threshold/mesoamerica/" i)
```

I need to find a way to use the "i" variable in the outExtractByMask.save. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish the task.  The general idea here is to create a full output file path using `os.path.join()` and input that into the `.save` command

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = "C:/rasters/threshold"
outws = "C:/SIG/MelasCA_30runs_avg/threshold/mesoamerica"
mask = "C:/GIS/mesoamerica.tif"

rasterlist = arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "Raster")
for i in rasterlist:
    outExtractByMask = ExtractByMask(i, mask)
    outname = os.path.join(outws, str(i)) # Create the full out path
    outExtractByMask.save(outname)
```